# How to change file names to name of directory that they're in?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a folder named "Projects". In that folder, I have multiple folders for my music projects, that have different names, and in each one of these I have an FL Studio project file (.flp), along with project's data, like Wave and MP3 files. But all of the FLP files have the default name ("untitled.flp"). Is there a way to change file names to names of directories that they're in?

I thought that I can make a batch or VBS file, but I'm not sure how should I program it.

Pseudo batch code:

```
:loop
for each "untitled.flp" in "D:\Google Drive\Projects" goto change
exit
:change
set variable="untitled.flp directory"
ren "untitled.flp" %variable%
goto loop
```

I'm running Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (untitled.flp) DO IF EXIST "%%a" (
 FOR %%s IN ("%%~dpa.") DO ECHO REN "%%a" "%%~nxs.flp"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

The first `for` assigns the directoryname from the entire tree to `%%a` and appends the filename. The `if` gates out directorynames where the file is absent and the inner `if` constructs the full pathname of `%%a` and appends `.`, treating the entire resultant name as a filename; then the `ren` command renames the full filename of the file found to the name and extension part of the file's parent directoryname.

Comment: I haven't launched it yet. But what will happen, if I have two FLP files in one directory?

Comment: It will only detect and attempt to change the `untitled.flp` file. It will be unable to change the name `untitled.flp` if the new filename already exists.

Comment: **Reading** Magoos answer will help. There is a preventive echo. What you want to do if there already is a file of type `.flp` with the name of the parent directory is up to you.